# The Windows Process Activation Service failed to generate an application pool config file

Tags: windows, iis, was

I suddenly cannot start IIS anymore on my Windows 2008 R2 server. The depending "Windows Actication Service" does not start.

In the Event Viewer I can see the following message:

"The Windows Process Activation Service failed to generate an application pool config file"

I've checked all IIS config files for typo's, none can be found.

I've tried to remove the IIS role from the server, which results in an error.

I'm totally desperate here. I've looked on Google for several hours, but none of the suggestions I've found helped.

Comment: See this SO post for a potential fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742076/iis-app-pool-and-was-stop-automatically-with-with-event-id-5189

Answer (score 0):

Something has messed up permissions and the user account under which WAS runs does not have permission to create its working files. Probably you installed a service pack or similar.

Rebuild the box and apply all service packs to Windows *before* you install WAS, and then let it update itself and *then* install your own stuff.

Rebuilding boxes is no fun and takes far too long. Learn to use virtualisation and undo disks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another working server, you can import IIS configuration from there via Shared Configuration.  I was able to resolve this error by doing so.