# IIS App Pool and WAS stop automatically with with event id 5189

Tags: asp.net, iis, was

When starting the website, app pool stops automatically with some errors. Tried turning IIS and WAS features off and enabled. Didn't help. applicationhost.config file is proper and not corrupt

Below are the errors from event viewer

The worker process for application pool 'testpool' encountered an error 'Cannot read configuration file
' trying to read configuration data from file '\?\', line number '0'.  The data field contains the error code.

The Windows Process Activation Service failed to generate an application pool config file for application pool 'testpool'. The error type is '5'. To resolve this issue, please ensure that the applicationhost.config file is correct and recommit the last configuration changes made. The data field contains the error number.

Answer (score 6):

Managed to find the root cause.

Tried running process monitor (procmon.exe) when starting the website. svchost.exe process is trying to create a folder in following location (C:\inetpub\temp\appPools) with app pools name.

And somehow there was a folder shortcut with name same as app pool. WAS process is trying to create the folder when starting the app pool. I have now cleared that folder and retried. It worked!

Comment: Good find, I had a similar issue when I upgraded from Windows 10 to the Creators Fall Update (1709). Not sure if it was related though.

Comment: I just upgraded to 1803 and have this problem with WAS, error 2. I renamed apppools to apppools2 and attempt to start WAS. It creates the needed folder and then terminates the same so there is something else causing the problem. Looking at procmon does not show anything obvious.